# Image upload in node js

Tags: node.js, file-upload

Im new to node js now i want to do image upload.so i downloaded express framework to handle the upload.Please help me how to handle that upload in server side.

i created form like this how to handle this in back end node js

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/file-upload">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="file" name="thumbnail">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: The [`multipart` example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/multipart/index.js) and [docs](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html) should help you get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method for uploading

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

    // get the temporary location of the file
    var tmp_path = req.files.thumbnail.path;
    // set where the file should actually exists - in this case it is in the "images" directory
   target_path = '/tmp/' + req.files.thumbnail.name;
    // move the file from the temporary location to the intended location
    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
            if (err) throw err;

        });
    });
});
```

While retriving show that path in this method

```
fs.readFile(target_path, "binary", function(error, file) {
    if(error) {
      res.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      res.write(error + "\n");
      res.end();
    } else {

      res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});
      res.write(file, "binary");

    }
 });
```

Refer [nodejs expressjs upload images and display them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404164/nodejs-expressjs-upload-images-and-display-them/12419974#12419974) for more details

Comment: You using express rite?Add this method directly to your main file.It should work,But add the routes to the supporting files.Google more you will get it.

Comment: This thing will store the image to your tmp directory.And the same will be retrieved.Add the target path to the database you are using.And while retrieving extract the path and pass that as the parameter for retrieval.

Comment: for the action part of your form specify upload,or else change the upload given in my method as per your form specs.

Comment: main file means i dint get.now i created one js in server within that i added this.

Comment: yeap do one thing add your form method in any view file basically jade or anything which you are using.And then add it to your js file.Change the form action to 'upload' to avoid confusions.And then rest all will work as described above.Hope it is clear.

Comment: Why need you unlink after rename?