# Converting php file upload end point to node.js/express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Sorry i havent used file uploads in node.js before

Currently i cam using angular service that uses `FormData` and submits a $http post request to php and there it is uploaded with `move_uploaded_file()` that is working fine

Angular .js code

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
        var uploadUrl = "upload.php";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```

html

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
```

**How** can i get this into node.js express route?

i have **read** other questions on stack overflow but i cant quite get it that were will the data be going in `res.body`? or `res.files` and how to finnaly upload them

my undesrtandings about it is that it will be something like this

```
routes.post("/upload",function(req,res,next){
 console.log(req.Files); 
 console.log(req.body); 

  });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image upload in node js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524804/image-upload-in-node-js)

Comment: @jakerella that solution is not working